# React-Native: Could not resolve project :react-native-gpay

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, google-pay

Hi there I am integrating google pay api using `react-native-gpay` but I have got an issue

Steps to install react-native-gpay

1- `npm i react-native-gpay`

2- `react-native link react-native-gpay`

3- Added in dependency block of android/app/build.gradle `compile project(':react-native-gpay')`

4- added `import com.reactlibrary.RNGpayPackage;` in MainActivity.java

5- Replaced `getPackages` method in MainApplication.java with below code() **>**

```
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          packages.add(new RNGpayPackage()); // added a package in the list returned by getPackages()
          return packages;
        }
```

and also imported in MainApplication.java `import com.reactlibrary.RNGpayPackage;`

6- My `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'Pmt'
include ':react-native-gpay'
project(':react-native-gpay').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gpay/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

I checked on GitHub too to resolve the issue like [this](https://github.com/hellochirag/react-native-GPay/issues/2)

But I couldn't find any answer. I am getting the following issue in my console

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-gpay.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gpay:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Comment: You're importing the module like as follow: `import GPay, { GooglePayImage } from 'react-native-gpay'`, right? Can you add some code to the question?

Comment: No I am not importing right now. Is it necessary to import it to get rid of this issue

Comment: it seems like the installation didn't finished correctly, try to reinstall it :

npm install react-native-gpay --save

Comment: It did not work either.